# A Question on Occupancy Model

Tags: probability, combinations

How many arrangements are there when you put $n$ distinguishable balls into $k$ buckets? Each bucket must contain at least one ball. What if the balls are indistinguishable?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your bins are distinguishable since you don't specify. If bins are indistinguishable the problem changes.

If the balls are distinguishable then you are counting the number of onto functions since you require at least one ball in each bin. This can be counted with the principle of inclusion and exclusion. You can find this argument many places.

For indistinguishable ball do the following. Place your $n$ balls on the table. In between the balls there are $n-1$ places chose $k-1$ of these to place dividers. Notice this splits the balls into $k$ groups and each group has at least one ball. Thus there are $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways the place the indistinguishable balls onto the bins while ensuring each bucket has at least one ball.

Answer (score 0):

If the balls are distinguishable, then you have to choose $k$ balls to distribute into the $k$ buckets. These $k$ balls can be ordered in $k!$ ways. The remaining $(n-k)$ distinguishable balls can be placed in any bucket. If the balls were indistinguishable, this would be the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem. Now that they are distinguishable, for each star and bar partitioning, there are (n-k)! ways to order the balls, so if the balls are distinguishable, I believe the answer is:
$$
{n \choose k}k!{{n-1}\choose {k-1}}(n-k)!
$$

If the balls are indistinguishable, we still need to select, but the order doesn't matter, so this should just be selected the $k$ balls to ensure the bins are non-empty, and then star-and-barring the remaining $n - k$, giving:

$$
{n \choose k}{{n-1}\choose {k-1}}
$$

Comment: Because of the at least one ball restriction, for distinguishable we need to use Inclusion/Exclusion, see Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind. And for indistinguishable, see Stars and Bars. Because of the non-empty condition, the answer is $\binom{n}{k-1}$. A good summary of related problems can be found in Wikipedia, the Twelvefold Way.

Comment: Why doesn't selected k balls to pre-populate the k buckets to ensure non-empty status, and now treating them as allowing to be empty with respect to the remaining n-k balls work? I will certainly defer to your expertise, but where is the flaw in the argument? Thank you.

Comment: That would work in the indistinguishable case. Then if you use Stars and Bars, you are left with $n-k$ balls, not $n$.  We cannot prepopulate in the distinguishable case, end up multiply counting.

Comment: Typo above. Stars and Bars gives $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Comment: Ahh. Yes, of course. So here, $n$ is actually $n - k$ (as I wrote, :doh:) and thus the proper arrangement is ${n - 1}\choose{k-1}$, correct because we cannot choose 0,so we have $k - 1$ buckets.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, is it correct now?

Comment: I think you over counted, when you multiplied by $(n-k)!$

Comment: Why? In that section, the balls are distinguishable, so once the $n-k$ "extra" balls are distributed in the $k-1$ "empty" buckets (because they are pre-populated) they can be ordered in $(n-k)!$ distinguishable ways leaving the same number of balls in the buckets.